# What causes containers to be recreated during docker compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 services in docker compose, 1 pulled from dockerhub (rasa) and another (rasa actions server) built from a dockerfile in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` (both under `under core-bot` folder).

I have 2 users on VM (the root `ubuntu`, and `hanqi`).
Starting from `docker compose up -d` in `ubuntu`, when I alternately run 1,2,1,2...

1. `cd /home/hanqi/core-bot && docker compose up -d`
2. `cd /home/ubuntu/core-bot && docker compose up -d`

I see the container from the image pulled from dockerhub getting restarted, while the container from the dockerfile is always running.

The rasa service has a bind mount

```
services:
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:2.7.1-full
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

**Question 1. Generally, what causes containers to be restarted? (I only changed directory and made no code changes).**

**Question 2. Why is only the container from dockerhub image (rasa) being restarted but not the dockerfile one?**

I suspect it has something to do with the bind mount being just a relative path to current directory. So I changed it to an absolute path

```
services:
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:2.7.1-full
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/core-bot:/app
```

and ran `docker compose down -v && docker compose up -d --build`, but same behaviour persists.

I tried `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' container_id` and it gave me `[{bind  /home/hanqi/core-bot /app  rw true rprivate}...]`, so the source `"Source": "/home/hanqi/core-bot"` was not what i expected (`/home/ubuntu/core-bot`) and i'm doubting if the docker-compose.yml updates got picked up by the containers.

**Question 3. Was `docker compose down -v && docker compose up -d --build` the correct workflow to update a `docker-compose.yml` generally, or a bind mount specifcally?**

Comment: Cab you share the logs for restarting container?

Comment: Is it getting restarted, or destroyed and recreated?  What does the container that doesn't get restarted look like?  You should not need the `docker-compose down -v` command in typical use, but I'd also expect you shouldn't need to replace an image's entire `/app` directory with a bind mount.

Comment: @DavidMaze 

The `Started` word was previously `Recreate` for a few seconds, then becomes `Starting` for very short moment, then stays at `Started`

`Running 2/2`
`Container core-bot-rasa-1 Started`
`Container core-bot-actions-server-1  Running`

(Somehow can't do triple backticks in comments)

Comment: Did you find the reason? I have the same problem but with my Loki container